# Running multiprocessing inside a function doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In my program I'm making requests to a server. I want these requests to run in parallel to download data faster, so I used multiprocessing. At first the program worked, but then I wanted to turn the entire project into a function. I isolated the problem at the multiprocessing, and realized that the function works without it.

I tried removing multiprocessing, and the function worked perfectly. When I tried multiprocessing again, the function failed. I want to have the multiprocessing run my function inside the function in parallel instead of having the functions run in series.

Python:

```py
# This doesn't work    
def download():
    data = [name1, name2, name3, name4]
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        result = pool.map(randomFunction, data)

# This works
def download():
    data=[name1, name2, name3, name4]
    randomFunction(data[0])
    randomFunction(data[0])
    randomFunction(data[0])
    randomFunction(data[0])
```

Comment: *"I want these requests to run in parallel to download data faster"* Leaving aside your issues with getting the multiprocessing framework to do what it says on the tin, why do you think this is going to work? Do you hope for more throughput (only going to work in special cases)? Or are trying to reduce serial latency (better chance on this, though still no guarantee)?

Comment: remove  `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: I am downloading large video files. If I do it with the second method, it would take 30 seconds to download the first file, and then it would begin to download the second one. The purpose of doing it in parallel is that it would download them all at the same time and significantly reduce latency. There are ways of working around the problem, although I am interested in hearing a method of solving it as I have just learned python today and am trying to get a better feel for the language.

Comment: Removing      if ___name == '__main__':      did not work.

Comment: How much of those half-minute downloads are *latency* (waiting on responses from remote sites) instead of your pipe just taking a lot of time to move the actual bytes?  Depending on this-n-that you might very well be looking at a possible gain of a few percent for all your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use threading.

```py
import threading

def your_function():
    ###whatever your downloader is
t1 = threading.Thread(target=your_function)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=your_function)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Ive had success using this to speed up requests a lot. This may or may not save you anytime but its worth a try.

Would be helpful to see more of your code as well.